# Logic. How to deal with free variables?

Tags: logic

The task is to depict the following set:

$$\left\{ <x,y> \in \mathbb{R^2} \, |\, x^2 + y^2 > 1 \Rightarrow \exists z \, (x^2 + (y − z)^2 \leq \frac{1}{4}) \right\}$$

Comment: So $z$ should be in $\mathbb{R}$ too?

Comment: Edited. This is what I found as an exercise. I  think it is needed to assume that  $z \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: There is no missing parenthesis, just a mashup of notation. $<>$ signs used for both ordered pair and less than greater than signs.

Comment: @mathreadler: Thanks, it appears I am having problems reading...

Comment: It's ok. I was also a bit confused at first.

Comment: I'm just glad I didn't have to add a huge parenthesis :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition has the form $P(x,y) \implies Q(x,y)$,
so $(x,y)$ is in the set **iff** $P(x,y)$ is false **or** $Q(x,y)$ is true.

Hence it is the union of sets of the form
$\{ (x,y) | \lnot P(x,y) \}$ and $\{ (x,y) | Q(x,y) \}$.

$P(x,y)$ is false **iff** $x^2+y^2 \le 1$, hence it contains the closed unit ball.

$Q(x,y)$ is true **iff** there is some $z$ such that $(x,y) \in \overline{B}((0,z), {1 \over 2})$.

Draw a picture of the collection $\overline{B}((0,z), {1 \over 2})$, and a simpler description will become obvious.

> $\{ (x,y) | Q(x,y) \} = \{ (x,y) | \  |x| \le {1 \over 2} \}$.

Comment: I think $\frac 14$ should be replaced with $\frac 12$ in all instances.

Comment: @Ennar: Thanks for catching that, you are of course correct. It would appear that I am unable to take square roots as well :-).

Comment: You are welcome. Well, it's just that we usually deal with unit balls, and square root of $1$ happens to be $1$, but not so with other distances. Easy oversight for anyone to make :)

Comment: Does $\overline{B}$ mean ball ? Why is it overlined? Also, we have to assume that free variable $z \in \mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: The overline means the closure, so $\le$ rather than $<$. And yes, I would presume $z \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @copper.hat you assigned $0$ to variable $z$ but as well you could go for $z = \frac{1}{2}$ and then $Q(x,y)$ holds true for $(x,y) = (0,0)$ , right?

Comment: I don't understand your question, I didn't assign $z$ to any particular value. Yes, $(0,0)$ is in the set. You need to look at the entire collection of $\overline{B}((0,z), {1 \over 2})$ as $z$ ranges through the reals.

Comment: I don't get it. I treat $z$ as variable. Some $z$ always  exists for which $(x,y) \in \overline{B}((0,z), {1 \over 2})$ holds true

Comment: $z$ is a variable. If $|x| > {1 \over 2}$ you can find no $z$ such that $(x,y) \in \overline{B} ((0,z), {1 \over 2}$. Note that if $|x| > {1 \over 2}$, then $x^2 > {1 \over 4}$.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you really want is a general method, but I just could not resist showing a short cut on this one.

**Spoiler** May contain too much of a solution and therefore ruin a bit of the fun.

---

Smallest value of the expression on the right will be at $z=y$, since squares can not be smaller than $0$ and $z$ does not affect anything else in the expression. For that $z$, we get the intersection between $x^2 \leq \frac{1}{4}$ and $x^2+y^2>1$, which is the intersection of

1. $x^2 \leq \frac{1}{4}$, equivalent to $|x| < \frac{1}{2}$ which is the interior of a strip focussed on the $x$:s which are $0$.
2. The outside of the circle centered at origo of radius 1.

Comment: do you mean $p \Rightarrow q$?

Comment: Yes I realized I probably got that wrong, and thought about deleting, but maybe it would be better to just fix what is wrong since the derivations of the sets I did aren't really wrong but how they interact.

Comment: Anyway, I like your "trick", thanks.